# Linux, ignore reference to a $variable on command line. Take literal string instead

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In verilog I am grepping for tasks which all begin with $ symbol, an unfortunate crossover with unix

When  grepping

```
grep -r -F "$finish" /path/to/dir
```

Returns

```
finish: Undefined variable.
```

How can it be interpreted literally IE not an environment variable.

Comment: Use single quotes, `'$finish'` or escape the `$`, `"\$finish"`.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite you command like:

```
 grep -r -F \$finish /path/to/dir
```